# Is it possible to access attribute that is delegated to another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delegates

When creating app I had model Order with attribute `delivery_option`. After some time, I had to create "higher level" `order` to group orders and created MainOrder.
Now, Order delegates `:delivery_option` to MainOrder, but about 70% of MainOrders has `delivery_option == nil` because where created during migration, just to cover Orders from past. I couldn't fill up `main_order.delivery_option = order.delivery_option` because there can be many orders in one main_order, each with different `:delivery_option`.

Is it possible to somehow access `order.delivery_option` without hitting `order.main_order.delivery_option`?

code looks like this:

```
class MainOrder
  has_many :orders
end

class Order
  belongs_to :main_order
  delegates :delivery_option, to: main_order, allow_nil: true
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`attributes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-attributes) method returning  a hash with attribute values:

```
order = Order.first
# fetches delivery_option from the main_order
order.delivery_option 

# returns value stored in orders table belonging to the order
order.attributes["delivery_option"]

# you can also use
order.attribute(:delivery_option)
```